# How do I compare results from a for loop to a column of a csv file?

Tags: python

I have a csv file of some text and their class, and am using a rule-based method to classify them.
The csv file is in columns of the text and the class:

looks like this:

Text, Class

text1, class1

text2, class2

I wrote a for loop that goes through each piece of text and classifies them.

```
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\kahnl\Downloads\train\train.csv', 'rU') as infile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(infile)
    data={}
    for row in reader:
        for header, value in row.items():
            try:
                data[header].append(value)
            except KeyError:
                data[header]=[value]
textt=data['Text']
class_one=data['Class']

for i in textt:
    #classify text
```

The text is classified as:

```
text_class='#class'
```

how do I check each one with the correct class in the csv file?

Comment: What do you mean by checking each with the correct class? Do you need to `Class` corresponding to each `Text` as it was in .csv?

Comment: I want text_class (the class found by the rule-based method) to correspond to the class stated in the Class column of the csv

Comment: If you already knew the correct value for each, then you wouldn't need to load it from a file. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Can you give a [mcve] with expected output?

Comment: I know the correct value of each, because I am using a pre-labeled dataset, but I want to test the accuracy of a method. So right now my code guesses the class for each sentence, and I want to compare each one with its actual class so I can calculate the accuracy. Expected output should be:  class1, guessed_class,          and if they are the same, it will be labeled as correct.

Comment: How about reading .csv into a Pandas DataFrame with 2 cols: `Text`, `Class` and then create your `Predicted Class` column. To check accuracy, see how many rows have same/different classes for `Class` and `Predicted Class`?

Comment: That worked, thanks.